# How to delete all item version besides default language?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-rocks

For some reason sitecore has created multi-versions in all languages.
Is there way to delete all the version and the languages besides default language through  Site core Rocks Query?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can delete the language item from the system/Languages and it will remove this language version from all the items automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove this language from the system and it will take care this item, then publish the site - this will resolve this issue.

If you still have any issue - Please remove this explicitly, Below is the sample code

I have used this code to add version for all languages, May be this help to remove explicitly.

var homeItemA = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(Landings.HomeItem);
            var languageA = Sitecore.Globalization.Language.Parse("en-SG");//new language version

```
        var master = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master");

        var allItems = master.GetItem(homeItemA.Paths.FullPath).Axes.GetDescendants();



        foreach (var blog in allItems)
        {
            Item ca = master.GetItem(blog.Paths.FullPath, languageA);


            using (new Sitecore.SecurityModel.SecurityDisabler())
            {
                try
                {
                    if (0 == ca.Versions.Count)
                    {
                        ca.Versions.AddVersion();
                    }


                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ca.Editing.CancelEdit();

                }
            }
        }
```

See [my own blog for more details](http://jitendrasoni.blogspot.co.uk/2015/02/sitecore-how-to-create-new-language.html)